# how do i check if a method has already been called?

Tags: php

I have a class that loads certain parts of my page. What I want to do is this

```
index.php

$obj->load('admin');
```

In my class in the constructor I have a check to see if the URI contains the segment `/admin/` and if it does then it auto loads the admin page:

`$this->load('admin');`

now both work fine, I just realized that if I have both entries in my project then it will load the `admin` initialization twice.

Is there a way for my to check if the `load()` method has already been called and if the parameter is `==` to `admin`?

Comment: use singleton pattern http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `static` cache:

```
function load($what) {

  static $loaded = array();

  if (!isset($loaded[$what])) {

    // Load..

    // Mark as loaded
    $loaded[$what] = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
    private $loaded = false;
    function someFunc() {
        $this->loaded = true;
    }

    function loaded() {
        return $this->loaded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Keep a object member variable variable and keep a flag when the load admin is called for first time. Check the flag for during the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest - create additional variable called say '$invokedAlready'. Set it first to 'false'. In your method place this:

```
if ( $invokedAlready )
{
    // do sth
}
else
{
    // first invocaion
    // do sth else
    $invokedFirst = true;
}
```